# Keep track of different kind of users once they are logged in

Tags: mysql, database, mobile, flex-mobile

I'm building a mobile app using flex mobile that have two kinds of users: Regular users who have to register and login and Facebook users who can login using their Facebook account. Then each user can add a video to his personal list or delete one from the same list. The question is how am I going to distinguish between regular users and Facebook users once they are logged in so I can access to the database and load a list of each user's added videos. My database contains 3 tables : the regular users table, the Facebook users table and videos table.

Comment: I would assume those users added videos are attached to some type of unique user identifier which is completely independent of how they logged in.  IS that not the case?  If it is; then get the list of user's videos based on that unique ID.  If that is not the case; you'll have to explain more.

Comment: Every regular user will have his unique auto incremented id.The same thing for every facebook user.Every user (regular or facebook user) can add a new video to his list ; every video added will have his unique id as a primary key.

Comment: Then, I don't understand the problem.  Why do you need to know the type of login the user used to retrieve the list of videos?

Comment: Consider this example : a regular user logged into the application, now we need to load his personal list of videos from the database.The question is how can i tell which videos that user added so i can retreive their names in a list ?

Comment: When videos are created; also save the ID of the user who created it.  This would most likely be in the form of putting the user's unique ID in the video table as a foreign key.

Comment: It will not work in the case of Two different kind of users(a regular user and a facebook user ) who  have the same id and it's possible that they choose the same name for the video that every one could add.In that case , both videos will end up with the same name and the same user's ID.

Comment: You said that "every regular user will have his unique auto incremented id. The same thing for every facebook user."  It is up to you to make sure every user has a unique ID.

Answer (score 0):

**using the response object of Fb.getLoginStatus , you can identify the user logged in from facebook**

To determine if a user has authenticated your app:

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });

Response objects

**If the user has authenticated your application, the response object** will look like this:

{
    status: 'connected',
    authResponse: {
        accessToken: '...',
        expiresIn:'...',
        signedRequest:'...',
        userID:'...'
    }
}

By testing for the presence of the authResponse object within the response object, you can be sure the user has authenticated your app and you can begin to make further calls to the Facebook APIs. If the authResponse object is not present, the user is either not logged into Facebook, or has not authorized your app.

**The most useful parts of the authResponse object are the userID (the user's ID) and the accessToken. The access token can be used to make requests to the Facebook APIs on behalf of that user. The userID is the unique identifier for the user who's present in your app.**

http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/2011/10/create-a-mobile-facebook-flex-application-in-flash-builder-4-5-part-1.html

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/getting-started-with-facebooksdk-actionscript3.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_1